# Validation messages no longer localized after publish

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Let's say that i have a model with property.

```
[Required]
public string XXX { get; set; }
```

As you can see I have validation attribute [Required]. Let's try to leave it empty in a form and the error message appears. The application works on VS development server.

> Pole XXX jest wymagane.

So far it's OK. The localized message appears. But after publish the localization is lost.

> Field XXX is required.

First think that we should check is the culture on published app (I log it to the file and display it in the view):

> Culture: pl-PL
>   CultureUI: pl-PL

Seems OK, so where's the problem?

The published app is installed on different machine where Windows Server locale is set to en-GB, but it shouldn't matter as far as in my app culture is different, right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC validation message does not get localized](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229813/asp-net-mvc-validation-message-does-not-get-localized)

Comment: Why don't you override builtin error messages by providing explicit messages like `[Required( ErrorMessage = "Wymagana wartość")]`

Comment: @WiktorZychla Because I have hundreds of models and I'd like to finally figure it out why it doesn't work correcly.

Comment: @GSerg The solution you provided is exaclty what I don't want to do and doesn't ansewer my question - "why localization stopped working after publish".

Comment: Localization stopped after publishing because your published application does not contain the literal localized strings. Instead it contains instructions for the .NET framework to take the said strings from its resources during runtime. Your computer has resources in Polish, so it displays Polish for you. The server does not have resources in Polish, so it falls back to resources in English. To fix it, you provide the server with the Polish resources by installing the Polish language pack. How does that not answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, only changing the configuration in web.config is not enough to apply the culture. What works in my test scenario was download the 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Full Language Pack'.

After install [this package](http://www.microsoft.com/pl-PL/download/confirmation.aspx?id=3324) (in Polish), only changing the globalization in my web.config

```
<system.web>
  <globalization uiCulture="pl-PL" culture="pl-PL" />
```

was enough to showing all validation messages in Polish.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found a similar problem. After publishing my application, validation was no longer displayed.

In my case, to solve this problem i had to include this attribute in my web.config:

```
<configuration>
   <appSettings>    
      <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
```

After that, the validation was displayed.

Comment: It doesn't answer the OP, the error messages are displayed in his case but not in the correct langage