# ValidationMessageFor Language

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, windows-server-2008, globalization, culture

I am using **ASP.NET MVC 5**. I am trying to get the message of the `ValidationMessageFor` in French.

> "The xxx field is required" -> "Le champ xxx est manquant".

I have deployed my website in 2 servers

- Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 + IIS 7
- Windows Server 2012 + IIS 8

I added in my **web.config** this following line:

```
<globalization culture="fr-FR" uiCulture="fr" />
```

Finally, I succeed in doing the "translation" for the WS 2012. But not with WS 2008, when I submit a form, I still have *"The xxx field is required"* in English.

I conclude that it's a problem of server configuration. But which one?

I have tried to:

- Set the globalization option to French (fr) into IIS
- Setup a French language pack into WS (my server is now in French)
- ...etc etc

If anyone has a solution for me...

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC validation message does not get localized](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229813/asp-net-mvc-validation-message-does-not-get-localized)

Comment: and then you could check this [link](http://serverfault.com/questions/219777/iis-7-net-globalization-settings)

Comment: Yes Joe you're right it's duplicate but thank you it works !

Answer (score 1):

You need to install language pack on the server on which you are hosting your site. Go to Microsoft's official site and you can download them.

1. Go to below link and select language from dropdown list. In your
   case "French".

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1246

2. Then click on download button.
3. Then save file on your disk and install it.

Please let me know if you have any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 Language Pack: http://www.microsoft.com/fr-FR/download/details.aspx?id=30667 fixed my issue.