# Kendo error messages not using the culture

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

While using this tutorial: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/globalization, I set current culture through the `web.config`

```
<system.web>
    <globalization uiCulture="ru-RU" culture="ru-RU" />
    ...
</system.web>
```

include the js culture file and set kendo culture

```
    @{
        var culture =  System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.ToString();
    }

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2014.2.903/cultures/kendo.culture." + culture + ".min.js")"></script>

    <script>
        kendo.culture("@culture");
    </script>
```

Everything is working perfectly except of error messages.

When I'm using my local machine which is using ru-RU culture on the OS level, kendo shows localized error messages, such as " Требуется поле Тип оплаты." (I'm sorry for the foreign language, that's just for example)

But when I deploy application to the server, where OS culture is set to en-US, it shows non-localized error messages, such as "The Тип оплаты field is required."

Web.config and _Layout.cshtml content are identical to local after the deploy, so it's not web.config transormation problem

I'm using kendo 2014.2.903

Comment: Have you tried writing out your `var culture` to see what is actually being passed to kendo?

Comment: @JudgeBread, yeah it renders as kendo.culture("ru-RU"); Futhermore, the bug consists only i error messages, for example grid button labels are fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. It wasn't kendo, it was standart Html.ValidationMessageFor control. I haven't installed .NET Framework Language Pack for russian language to my server. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27919446/validationmessagefor-language) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use globalization on your web.config like that:

```
<system.web>
    <globalization culture="tr-TR" uiCulture="tr-TR" />
    ...
</system.web>
```

**Update:** If you want to use globalization according to the user or server settings, then remove this line above in the web.config. Because this line make the globalization independent from the user or server settings.

Comment: This was already set this way
I'm added some degree of verbosity to the question

Comment: I updated my answer. If you want to use localization according to the user or server settings, you need to remove that line as I explained.